# Hot to get a few seconds ahead result of getByteTimeDomainData()?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio, audio-streaming, web-audio-api

[getByteTimeDomainData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode/getByteTimeDomainData#Syntax) is used in Youtube player. 
It returns the current waveform.
I wonder if it is possible to get the waveform of the future moment?

Usage example:

```
const audioCtx = new AudioContext();
const videoSrc = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(video); // Youtube video
const analyser = audioCtx.createAnalyser();
videoSrc.connect(analyser);
const dataArray = new Uint8Array(analyser.fftSize); // Uint8Array should be the same length as the fftSize 
analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(dataArray); // fill the Uint8Array with data returned from getByteTimeDomainData()
```

`getByteTimeDomainData` - copies current waveform in `dataArray`.
How do I get the future waveform without changing Youtube `video.currentTime`?